Assistance Required: Resolving Title Issue in ADA Compliant PDF Generation
We are encountering an issue related to the title element in the process of generating ADA-compliant PDF documents. Our current workflow involves utilizing HTML for layout design, alongside the iTextSharp library and C# for the actual PDF generation, ensuring ADA compliance using specific tags like article for an example.
Below is the code snippet we employ to incorporate the title in our PDF documents:
HTML Code:
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Guest Statement</title>
    <meta name="title" content="Statement">
</head>
<body>
    <article title="Statement">
</body>

C# Code:
var pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var writer = new PdfWriter(pdfStream))
{
writer.SetCloseStream(false);
using var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);

pdfDocument.SetTagged();

// Set the DocumentInfo
pdfDocument.GetDocumentInfo().SetTitle("Statement");
}

And while doing Accessibility Check getting below error. Even after trying all the ways in HTML, and C#.
Screenshot:

Despite these efforts, we are facing challenges as indicated by the Accessibility Check, which reports errors concerning the title tag. This persists regardless of the various methodologies we've tried within both HTML and C#.
How can we overcome this obstacle?

That is setting the title correctly, but it is not setting the viewer preference. You also need to specify that the title should be used instead of the filename which is the default.
pdfDocument.GetCatalog().SetViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().SetDisplayDocTitle(true));

iText has a tutorial demonstrating this.

This is a fairly common misnomer from checkers.
The inference is that the Title reports the title of documents as detailed in their document properties.
And there are at least two locations for a PDF title so we first double check those.

Older (depreciating) document /Info should have an entry perhaps like this
/Title (þÿ T i t l e)   that looks perfectly valid so let's check the second one

Newer (preferred) XMP metadata must include Title
    <dc:title>
        <rdf:Alt>
            <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Title</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Alt>
    </dc:title>



Looks good too, so what could it be?


Let's scan another file and bingo we see it has
/ViewerPreferences <</DisplayDocTitle true>>
So that is what is meant by "reports the title of documents".
